# Is there a way to side load an APK on a nexus 5 without google play and without enabling developer mode?

Tags: android, apk

There is no file explorer that comes with the Nexus 5, and when I try to copy the APK into the downloads folder I do not see it on the Nexus 5 UI.

Comment: Put it on a web page with the appropriate mime type.

Comment: there are free file explorers on the apps store that will allow you to install apks

Answer (score 2):

Send it to the email address associated with that device, as an attachment. You will be able to open the attachment and install the apk.

Developer mode doesn't need to be on, but you may need to enable installing from non-trusted sources.

Comment: Yeah this or something like dropbox/gdrive/any filehosting service will also work.